# Working with list of arrays and accesing its elements in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using two objects in my app.

First type looks like this:

[image]

and I can access the gender like this: data.results[0].gender

So to elaborate on this i decided to record all people in the data array and now i have an object that looks like this:

[image]

how do I reference and access names of selected people from an object like this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Based on the second screenshot, this is an array of objects. Lets call the array `arr` then you can access the name of the `i`-th person in the following way:
`arr[i].name.first` and `arr[i].name.last` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

To be fair, this seems like a poor/messy way to keep data in general, but maybe you could define a [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) between your people's ids or uuids or usernames, let's say, and the corresponding objects and then call them by their ids to retrieve the info you need on them:

```
const peopleMap = new Map();

for (person in array){
peopleMap.set(person.id.value, person)
}
```

ex.

```
let aparticularid = '92bd-asd1-24nas-213c-3cac-31ac'; 
let person = peopleMap.get(aparticularid);
let fullname = person.title + ' ' + person.first + ' '+ person.last;
```

Realistically you'd retrieve the particular id from elsewhere or some event. Or you can map names to the corresponding objects if you can guarantee their uniqueness(if they are not unique, the objects will be overridden in the map)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.map()` to iterate over the items of an Array.

Example -

```
yourArray.map(x => {
  const {title, first, last} = x.name;

  console.log(`${title} | ${first} } ${last}`)
})
```

```js
const yourArray = [
  {
    id: {name: 'HETU', value: 'NAANANFSF'},
    name: {title: 'Ms.', first: 'Mila', last: 'Heitet'}
  },
  {
    id: {name: 'Tom', value: 'TANN'},
    name: {title: 'Mr.', first: 'Tom', last: 'Altar'}
  },
  {
    id: {name: 'HARRY', value: 'HARSFF'},
    name: {title: 'Mr.', first: 'Harry', last: 'Krishna'}
  }
];

yourArray.map(x => {
  const {title, first, last} = x.name;

  console.log(`${title} | ${first} | ${last}`)
})
```

Comment: mapping doesnt work same as other suggestions . i'm trying to add previous runs using addHistory in a function like this :      const onClickHandler = () => {
        
        
        axios.get("https://api.randomuser.me/")
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res)
   
        const data = res.data.results["0"]
        setPosts(data)
        addHistory(history => [...history,data])
        console.log(history)
  
       
     but no matter i do i cant get anything from "history"
 
  })